# MigraDoc/PDFSharp TextFrame Centre Align

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using a Paragraph inside a TextFrame to get the text orientation to be displayed upwards this is working to nearly how i would like it to, the final issue i have got is the text seems to be left aligned, i have tried setting the Paragraph alignment to centre this didn't have no affect and can't see an option to do this with a TextFrame. The text outputted will not be the same everytime.

This is what i currently have

[image]

This is what i want to acheive

[image]

The following is the code i am using to acheive this using MigraDoc

```
for (int i = 0; i < section2Items.Length; i++)
{
    TextFrame colXTextFrame = bothSection2ItemHeadersRow.Cells[i + 1].AddTextFrame();
    colXTextFrame.Orientation = TextOrientation.Upward;
    colXTextFrame.Height = new Unit(140);

    Paragraph colXParagraph = new Paragraph();
    colXParagraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
    colXParagraph.AddText(section2Items[i].Section2ItemTitle);
    colXTextFrame.Add(colXParagraph);

    bothSection2ItemHeadersRow.Cells[i + 1].Borders.Bottom = new Border() { Color = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Color(255, 255, 255), Width = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Unit(0), Style = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.BorderStyle.None };
}
```

Comment: can you post some code? which language are you using? Have you tried vertical alignment instead of horizontal alignment, since you turned it around 90° ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code example that should work.

You can use the `MarginLeft` property of the `TextFrame` to shift it in the middle of the column.

```
// Create the table 
Table Table = section.AddTable();
Table.Borders.Width = 0.5;

// create 3 columns
Column column1 = Table.AddColumn("4cm");
Column column2 = Table.AddColumn("4cm");
Column column3 = Tabl.AddColumn("4cm");


// make the row
Row row = Table.AddRow();


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    TextFrame t = row.Cells[i].AddTextFrame();
    t.Orientation = TextOrientation.Upward;
    t.Height = new Unit(140);

    // set the left margin to half of the column width
    t.MarginLeft = this.Tabelle.Columns[i].Width/2;

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;       
    p.AddText("Test_" + i.ToString());

    t.Add(p);
}
```

this produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: This had no affect.

Comment: @ccStars I found it. See the edit please. Hope it helps

Comment: @ccStars did I overread the wrapping part in your question? Or what do you mean with "wraps" ?